# c# oop inheritance error

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

> Error  1   'WindowsFormsApplication3.student' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments    C:\Users\Marius\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\pregatiret\WindowsFormsApplication3\Form1.cs  32

```
public class persoana
{
    public string nume;



    public int varsta;


    public persoana(string num, int var)
    {
        this.nume = num;
        this.varsta = var;

    }


  public class student : persoana
   {
   public string facultate;
   public int grupa;
   public student(string nume,int varsta,string fac,int grupa) : base(nume,varsta){
       this.facultate = fac;
       this.grupa = grupa;


    }
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    persoana y;
    student x;
    ArrayList listaStudenti = new ArrayList();
    ListViewItem itm;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void inserareToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 m = new Form2();
        m.ShowDialog();
        if (m.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            x = new student();           **//I GET ERROR HERE**
        }          
    }
```

Comment: Your student class doesn't have an empty constructor.  It wants a nume, and a varsta, etc.

Comment: thank you. i also needed an empty constructor in the base class. thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a parameterless constructor to your  `student` class

```
public student()
{

}
```

When you declare a class and don't add any constructor, it inherits a default parameterless constructor from `object` class, but if you add a constructor that takes some arguments then default constructor will be ignored.You have to add it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor expects arguments you are not supplying

```
   x = new student();
```

Expects the parameters

```
  public student(string nume,int varsta,string fac,int grupa) : base(nume,varsta){
```